# Create a logarithmic scale with different increment in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, scale

Is it possible to somehow create a distribution of values at a degree scale? I have a distribution from (2^14)-5 to (2^14)+5 and a want to name the ticks on the axis as (2^14)-5, (2^14)-4 ... (2^14)+5. Should I do it manually or some way is existing?

Comment: First thing - I think "logarithmic scale" and "degree scale" are a bit misleading here. Second - you will have to set ticks labels manually. Your formatting - `(2^N)+-M` - is very specific, there is no chance it will be in `matplotlib`

Comment: If you want regularly spaced values that are as you describe, then that is **not** a logarithmic scale. A logarithmic scale would be if you wanted the values `2^(14-5)`, `2^(14-4)` etc. to be regularly spaced. What you describe is simply an *offset* for the axis.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved it in this way

```
increment=np.arange(-5,6)
scale = []
for i in a:
    if i>=0:
        scale.append(f'2^14+{i}')
    else:
        scale.append(f'2^14{i}')
```